# Generating functions formula

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Hi there I'm trying to establish a formula for $a_n$ using a generating function $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n t^n = A(t)$$which I have worked out as $A(t)=\frac{1}{2(2t+1)}-\frac{1}{2(4t-1)}-\frac{1}{t+1}$

Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Expand each of those fractions as a geometric series.

Comment: I've fixed some of your MathJax. My advice is to put one pair of dollars around the entire expression, not a separate pair around each term in said expression. Don't worry, though; it's a very common mistake.

Comment: Why has the OP edited and removed the original question completely off and added a low - quality version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $$A(t)=\frac12\frac{1}{1+2t}+\frac12\frac{1}{1-4t}-\frac{1}{1+t},$$we obtain the desired series provided $|t|<\frac14$, whence$$a_n=\frac12(-2)^n+\frac124^n-(-1)^n.$$